# Guidelines for Title in Dialog Box / Headings

Tags: usability, design-patterns, guidelines, standards

Consider a scenario where I have multiple operations (Add, Edit, Delete) on a Object (My Foo Object). Each of these operations when triggered by click of a corresponding action button, opens a dialog box.

What would be a the good UI Design Guideline for the Title Bar of the Dialog Box. Should the Title be 1 or 2 ? And Why ?

1. My Foo Object - Edit (Object - Operation)
2. Edit - My Foo Object (Operation - Object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1

Think about this: you have a subset of actions that belongs to an object. The object may change, you may have lots of objects, thus they are dynamic in nature. However, the actions are immutable. They will always be *Add, Edit, Delete* and **they will only exist as long as the object to which these actions reference exists**. On top of this, the title is for teh object, so it makes no sense to use the different actions available for that object as title. If you go to any e-commerce site, you'll see the title for any dialog is the product name, not the "buy" action!

For example, let's say you have this:

**Edit - My Foo Object**

**Add - My Foo Object (this is weird!)**

**Delete - My Foo Object**

As you can see, it already has some issues. But let's go further:

**Edit - My Foo Object 2**

**Add - My Foo Object 2 (this is weird!)**

**Delete - My Foo Object 2**

Now your users have no idea what's going on. And **each occurrence of "foo objects" will exponentially grow friction for user**

However, if you use

**Title** ---- action | action | action

it's clear that those actions are referencing the object.

Just in case, try adding your real titles instead of "foo" and you'll see how patterns emerge